# Bubble sort with linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list

My sort algorithm does not seem to work in some cases. I'm acting on a doubly linked list (with pointer on the previous and next ones). I submit the definition of my structure and the essential. I find myself with a infinite loop, with  specific cases like this one. I use `strcmp()` function, to sort.

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct s_file {
    char    *name;
    struct s_file     *next;
    struct s_file     *previous;
} t_file;

void swap_files(t_file *file, t_file *next)
{
    t_file *previous;

    previous = file->previous;
    if (previous)
        previous->next = next;
    file->next = next->next;
    file->previous = next;
    if (next->next)
        next->next->previous = file;
    next->next = file;
    next->previous = previous;
}

static t_file *sort_files(t_file *files)
{
    t_file *file;
    t_file *next;

    file = files;
    while ((next = file->next))
    {
        if (strcmp(file->name, next->name) > 0)
        {
            swap_files(file, next);
            if (!next->previous)
                files = next;
            file = files;
            continue;
        }
        file = file->next;
    }
    return (files);
}

void debug(t_file *files)
{
    while (files)
    {
        printf("=> %s\n", files->name);
        files = files->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    t_file second;
    t_file first;
    t_file third;

    first.name = "Poire";
    first.previous = NULL;
    first.next = &second;

    second.name = "Banane";
    second.previous = &first;
    second.next = &third;

    third.name = "Fraise";
    third.previous = &second;
    third.next = NULL;

    first = *(sort_files(&first));
    debug(&first);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's up with the massive space between the types (expect for the `*`) and the names of things?

Comment: @ThomasJager  I did not understand your question, but I do not want to manage the wildcard (like shell etc) in my code.

Comment: "It does not work in some cases" - Such as?

Comment: @Broman As in the example like this one, and other random

Comment: @ThomasJager: it looks like to coding convention in effect the *42* and *Epitech* computing schools. The OP posts from France. But the brace style is inconsistent with that, so it might just be the use of tabs and a poor choice of tab width. Using tabs is a bad idea exactly for this reason.

Comment: @ThomasJager  But I would like to know how you will manage the *, and spaces.

Comment: @Blue Personally, I use a single space between the type and the name, unless the type is a pointer, then all of the `*` are together, directly against the name, with a space between them and the rest of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely **not** overwrite `first` with the new head node of the list, because doing this causes the list to be corrupted. Just define a pointer to hold it:

```
    t_file *head = sort_files(&first);
    debug(head);
```

Also do not use `"` for standard header files:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Finally, even with these fixes, your bubble sort algorithm seems incorrect: when you swap the nodes at `file` and `next`, you should backtrack to the previous node just in case the `next` node was smaller than the previous node too.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
static t_file *sort_files(t_file *head) {
    t_file *file;
    t_file *next;

    file = head;
    while ((next = file->next) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(file->name, next->name) > 0) {
            swap_files(file, next);    // swap the nodes linkage
            file = next;               // next is now before file
            if (file->previous) {
                file = file->previous; // backtrack to the previous node
            } else {
                head = file;           // save the new head of list
            }
        } else {
            file = file->next;
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `swap_files` is overly complicated. It's perfectly adequate to just swap the data:

```
void swap_files(t_file *file, t_file *next)
{
    char *tmp = file->name;
    file->name = next->name;
    next->name = tmp;
}
```

And guess what? It solved the problem.

It was mentioned two issues with this solution in comments below, and I'd like to address them. First, this code could be less efficient if there are many data fields and second, chances are that you forget a field.

1. It's very unlikely that this would be the bottleneck, and if it is, deal with it then and not before. And when there is only one field, this code is much more effective. Arguing against a certain method because it would be slower if the circumstances were different is not a good argument.
2. Forgetting a field is a strong case against this. I have no objections there.

A solution to both above is to create a second struct for the data, like this:

```
struct data {
    char * name;
    int age;
    char * address;
    /* More fields */
}

struct s_file {
    struct data *data;
    struct s_file *next;
    struct s_file *previous;
}
```

You could argue for or against this. In a way it doesn't "feel like C", but on the other hand you get a nice separation on responsibilities.

Comment: I would have liked to try without doing that :)

Comment: @Blue Try it out. It works. Something is wrong in your swap_files, but since this is so much simpler there's little point in finding the bug in your code.

Comment: I also have the impression that his loop infinitely with this solution I'm going to try for cases like =>  *, and spaces.

Comment: @Blue you are right to not want to do that, the problems with that way are 1) if there are several fields rather than just one you have to swap all the fields which is expensive more the risk to forget to modify the swap in case a new field is added later, 2) if you have a pointer to a cell somewhere it stops to point to the right cell after the deep exchange. (No offence Broman, I understand anyway you propose that :-) )

Comment: @bruno Could you please explain what you meant with "if you have a pointer to a cell somewhere it stops to point to the right cell after the deep exchange"

Comment: @Broman I mean if you change the data into the cell, a pointer to a cell point after to that cell with a different data, so to an 'other' cell for the semantic/data point of view